# Ionic 2 Calendar Event

Tags: ionic2, calendar, ionic3

I want to ask about calendar event in ionic 2.

I have a script like this :
[myscript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opCtG.png)

This script for getting data event from my storage. But, I got this in my console log :
[myconsolelog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wiHC8.png)

And event also displays in my browser:
[mydisplay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R38JJ.png)

My question is, why my console logs in addschedule.ts 46 not showing data? Because when I am trying in a real device, I cant retrieve my event from local.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Please don't post your code as an image.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line number 46 will be executed first before line number 44 because [storage.get() will return promise](https://ionicframework.com/docs/storage/) in future (asynchronous operation). For not retrieving data from real device, we have to see the other part of the code. Also please post the code directly without images

Comment: Thank you, about the line 46 and 44 its clear. But i have to know why in real device after i add event and go to another page and come back again to page calendar, the event disappear. In browser working fine.

Comment: ionViewDidLoad will run only once per the page and after that it will use cache page, so your storage will not be called. use ionicviewwillenter or ionicviewdid enter. refer this link for life cycle events. https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/

Comment: if this resolves your issue mark this as correct answer

Comment: i dont know where is the problem, i try in browser working fine, but i real device not working. My event not load from my local storage

Comment: did you tried ionViewWillEnter and ionViewDidEnter?

Comment: Glad it helped :)